# how to only end breket in double breket regexp match

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```
const input = "sample(1)(2)sample(3)sample(4)(5)sample(6)(7)sample(8)sample(9)"
const regexp = new RegExp(????)   // <-- what i want
input.match(regexp)
result: [sample(1)(2), sample(3), sample(4)(5), sample(6)(7), sample(8), sample(9)]
```

how to match only end of breket???

Comment: Please explain your code little bit clear

Comment: I am sorry to everyone for my inexperience with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
input.match(/(.*?\))(?=($|[^(]+))/g)
```

(updated to also match at end of input)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. 
The regular expression you provided doesn't give the expected output as ```)``` is getting truncated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @EyadMohammedOsama.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @caedmon, your answer seems the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain my answer in details , but first i'll post the code:

```js
var input = "sample(1)(2)sample(3)sample(4)(5)sample(6)(7)sample(8)sample(9)";
var regex = /\)\w/;
var words = [];
while (input.search(regex) !== -1) {
    words.push(input.slice(0, input.search(regex) + 1));
    input = input.slice(input.search(regex) + 1, input.length); //start slicing right after the ")" until the end
}
words.push(input);
console.log(words);
```

The `regex` variable contains a regular expression that will match any `)` followed by a word character.

The `words` array contains separated words.

The `search()` method accept a string or a regular expression as a parameter , if there's a match , the index where this match occurred is returned , otherwise (if there's no match) -1 is returned.

The `slice(startIndex, endIndex)` method accepts two parameters , a start index , and an end index , it does return a part of the string starting from `startIndex` and ends at `endIndex - 1`.

At first , the search method will match **sample(1)(2)** ,so **sample(1)(2)** is pushed into the array and the input now consist of: **sample(3)sample(4)(5)sample(6)(7)sample(8)sample(9)**

Once again , the search method will match **sample(3)** ,so **sample(3)** is pushed into the array and the input now consist of: **sample(4)(5)sample(6)(7)sample(8)sample(9)**

Once again , the search method will match **sample(4)(5)** ,so **sample(4)(5)** is pushed into the array and the input now consist of: **sample(6)(7)sample(8)sample(9)**

Once again , the search method will match **sample(6)(7)** ,so **sample(6)(7)** is pushed into the array and the input now consist of: **sample(8)sample(9)**

Once again , the search method will match **sample(8)** ,so **sample(8)** is pushed into the array and the input now consist of: **sample(9)**

Now , the search method doesn't match the regular expression in **sample(9)** , because there's only `)` at the end , and no word character comes after it , that's why i'm pushing it manually at `words.push(input);`

You can read more about these methods in the following links:

`slice()`: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

`search()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. Today I learn a lot.